# Generate debug and signed Apk from my server without IDE

Tags: android, gradle, command-line, terminal, ant

I have source code of android app with gradle support. I want to generate Apk online through my server.

anyone guide me the commands for cmd or terminal by which, I can generate debug and signed apk using my source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generating debug and signed apk file from android project.you should add signingConfigs into your app moulde's build.gradle file as follow:

```
signingConfigs {
  ...
  release {
     ...
     keyAlias YOUR-KEY-ALIAS
     keyPassword YOUR-KEY-PASSWORD
     storeFile YOUR-KEYSTORE-FILE-PATH//here is your keystore file path
     storePassword KEY-STORE-PASSWORD
     ...
  }
   debug{//debug keystore
     ...
     keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
     keyPassword "android"
     storeFile rootProject.file("debug.keystore")//here is your keystore file path
     storePassword "android"
     ...
   }
   ...
}
```

in your buildTypes block add:

```
buildTypes {
...
    debug{
       ...
       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       ...
    }
    release {
       ...
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       ...
    }
...
}
```

finally,your can input command in your project's directory:`gradlew assemble`,that will output your porject's apk file in some derectory(YOUR-PROJECT-DIRECTORY/app/build/outputs/apk)

Comment: It's my honor.